# Reorder rows within groups

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am making a management system for a site that has a bunch of image galleries.  The interface will allow the user to add, delete, or reorder images within each gallery.

I have a table for all the images across all galleries together, with 'id' auto-incremented, and default for sort_order set to 0.

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| id |gallery_id | sort_order |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1         |         1  |
| 2  | 1         |         0  |
| 3  | 1         |         2  |
| 4  | 1         |         3  |
| 5  | 1         |         4  |
| 6  | 1         |         5  |
| 7  | 1         |         6  |
| 8  | 2         |         0  |
| 9  | 2         |         1  |
| 10 | 2         |         2  |
| 11 | 2         |         3  |
| 12 | 2         |         4  |
| 13 | 2         |         5  |
| 14 | 2         |         6  |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Here is the reorder query, using a serialized array via ajax:

```
if($_POST['item']) {
$order = 0;

foreach ($_POST['item'] as $id) {

$rearrange = $db->query
("UPDATE images SET sort_order = '".$order."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    $order++;
```

It limits sort_order according to the length of the array that is passed, and then defaults to 0 for the next group its comes to.  I can reorder, add, delete, and it always restricts changes to the gallery_id group I am editing.

(As an experiment, I inserted sort_order values ascending across all galleries, like this:

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| id |gallery_id | sort_order |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1         |         0  |
| 1  | 1         |         1  |
| 2  | 1         |         2  |
| 3  | 1         |         3  |
| 4  | 1         |         4  |
| 5  | 1         |         5  |
| 6  | 1         |         6  |
| 7  | 1         |         7  |
| 8  | 2         |         8  |
| 9  | 2         |         9  |
| 10 | 2         |         10 |
| 11 | 2         |         11 |
| 12 | 2         |         12 |
| 13 | 2         |         13 |
| 14 | 2         |         14 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
```

And when I reordered rows using my interface, it limited the sort_order within gallery_id groups, exactly as shown in the first table).

I'm looking for caveats to this approach.  Anyone done it this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE images
SET
    sort_order = FIELD(id, A, B, C, D, E)
WHERE gallery_id = N
    AND id IN(A, B, C, D, E)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it the same way, but I actually put the image inserted last by calculating the number of rows in each gallery. When a user wants to order he has to filter the list for a specific gallery first then he can sort the images in the gallery.

I cannot but point out the terrible security issues with your code. I really, really, really hope that you are not actually writing the queries like that as anybody can easily do whatever they want with your database.

http://xkcd.com/327/ comes to mind. If I submit an item like `0'; drop table images;` your entire table is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice.  I do indeed sanitize everything.  May I ask how do you filter the list for a specific gallery before reordering?

Comment: I use a framework, it shows me the list with filtering options, one of the filters is gallery_id. I do not allow them to sort until they filter on a specific gallery.